# Jquery color picker binding handler creates multiple divs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, color-picker

I am trying to use this jquery [color picker](http://laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/) with knockout.js. I have written custom banding handler to bind colorpicker input control with my viewModel color value.

Here is the Binding Handler code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.colorPicker = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().colorPickerOptions || {};
    $(element).colorPicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).colorPicker("value"));
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).colorPicker("destroy");
    });

},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());       
    $(element).colorPicker("value", value);        
}
```

and HTML :

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="colorPicker: newEvent().color, colorPickerOptions: { value:newEvent().color }"/>
```

Problem is that when I change the color it creates the multiple divs each time when I change the color as shown in image.

[image]

Can anyone please identiy whats the problem in my code??

Comment: what is `newEvent`?  can you provide a fiddle with the details of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the updated code for jQuery ColorPicker binding handler (to used with knockout.js libraray).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqColorPicker = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

    // set default value
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(value);

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().colorPickerOptions || {};
    $(element).colorPicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {            
        var observable = valueAccessor();            
        observable($(element).val());                        
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).colorPicker("destroy");
    });

  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(value);        
    $(element).change();        
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update code you're effectively creating new colorpickers.

When the color changes, the update function is called and there you create a new picker. If you try '*$(element).colorPicker("value", value);*' in firebug, you will see it's not a setter, but a constructor.

Comment: I am trying to use this, but cannot set text color, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/hmLbb9c0/2/