# knockout.js - Store class to viewModel

Tags: knockout.js

I am adding a class to a div via jQuery and I want to pass that class back to my viewModel.    I've looked into ko.datafor() and it doesn't seem to accomplish what I want (or it's fully possible that I just don't know how to use it properly).  What is the best approach to accomplish this?

**EDIT** - Let me explain some more:

I'm working on intergrating a colour picker with knockout.  You click on the colour picker icon and I build the list of colours to pick from like so:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < self.SponsorFilters().length; i++) {
                        var filter = self.SponsorFilters()[i];
                        if (filter.CssStyle() != null) {
                            $('.simplecolorpicker.picker').append('<div class="swatch' + i + '" role="button" tabindex="0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
                            $(".simplecolorpicker.picker .selected").hide();

                        }
                    }
```

Then when you pick the colour you want it is reflected on the icon via `"swatch+i"`.  I need that class to be passed back to my viewModel.
Ugh just typing this out makes no sense.  I might need to re-evaluate my strategy.

Comment: Why do you want to add a class to a div with jQuery? Knockout has the css binding that does this for you.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399892/jquery-color-picker-binding-handler-creates-multiple-divs

Comment: `Ugh just typing this out makes no sense. I might need to re-evaluate my strategy.` I can't help but Lol, not at you, but with you (because we have all been there and it becomes obvious once you start trying to explain your approach in written form). Chances are good that if you are starting to question it, it probably could be approached much differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom binding handler - Thanks Tyrsius!

Knockout

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.colorPicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                $(element).val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
                $(element).colorPicker();
                $(element).change(function () {
                    value(this.value);
                });
            }
        };
```

HTML

```
     <input class="jqColourPicker" type="text" data-bind="colorPicker: ColorCode, event: { change: $root.AdminSaveSponsorStyle }"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to write my knockout without any jQuery selectors at all. NONE. 0. Everything (well, most) you do with jQuery can be instead done with a knockout binding, or at least a custom binding that abstracts the jQuery stuff out of your viewmodel.

so instead of manually looping over sponsorFilters to create the swatch below, why don't you just use a foreach binding?

in your viewmodel

```
self.SponsorFiltersWithCSS = ko.computed(function() {
  var sponsorFilters = self.SponsorFilters();
  var filteredFilters = []
  for(var i = 0;i<sponsorFilters.length;i++) {
    if(sponsorFilters[i].CssStyle() != null) {
      filteredFilters.push(sponsorFilters[i]);
    }
  }
  return filteredFilters;
})
```

Markup

```
<div class="swatches" data-bind="foreach:SponsorFiltersWithCSS">
  <div role="button" data-bind="attr:{'class':'swatch' + $index}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```