# jQuery color picker edits not refflected in Knockout observable

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using a [jQuery color picker plugin](http://colpick.com/plugin) in my code, but it doesn't seem to work with KnockoutJS, as it is not updating my observable when im trying to output the value.

I have an input field, where I should be able to choose a color:

```html
<input class="colorpicker" id="bgcolor-one" name="bgcolor-one" type="text" data-bind="value: backgroundColor">
<br />
<span data-bind="text:backgroundColor">OUTPUT VALUE HERE</span>
```

And in my ViewModel I have:

```
self.backgroundColor = ko.observable("333333");
```

However, when using the colorpicker, it is not updating

```html
<span data-bind="text:backgroundColor">OUTPUT VALUE HERE</span>
```

The code for the colorpicker:

```
$('.colorpicker').colpick({
    colorScheme: 'dark',
    layout: 'hex',
    color: 'ff8800',
    onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
        $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
        // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.

        if (!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
    },
    onSubmit: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $(el).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        $(el).val(hex);
        $(el).colpickHide();
    }
})
```

Comment: shouldn't you be changing the value on the model (e.g somescope.backgroundColor (hexValue);) instead of manipulating the css style of an element directly?

Comment: The value of the model should be updated with this: $(el).val(hex);

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is by using custom bindings and a bindingHandler. Custom bindings are what allows us to use complex UI elements in our views and maintain the view/viewmodel separation. This is the documentation page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html.

What you should do is create a bindingHandler to wrap the jquery plugin initiation code. Binding handlers have 2 main methods: init() and update(). The *init* method is called when the binding is first applied to a DOM element. It is used to perform one-time initialization and it is where you should register the color picker event handlers to update the observable value and setup the picker the way you want by accepting some options as parameters. The *update* method is called every time the observable changes value and it is where you should tell the plugin to update the UI (in this case, call the *colpickSetColor* method).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399892/jquery-color-picker-binding-handler-creates-multiple-divs) question on SO. It'll show you how to create a bindingHandler for a color picker plugin. It's implemented using a different plugin but the idea is pretty much the same.