# How to set 'style:color' with colorpicker in knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I want to set the color of my text with a color picker. Found a nice little one with a knockout bindingshandler but cannot make it work.

HTML:

```
<div class="myPicker" data-bind="jqColorPicker: coverTextColor, colorPickerOptions: { value: coverTextColor}"></div>
<span class="title" data-bind="text: title, style: { color: coverTextColor}">blahblah</span>
```

Bindingshandler & viewmodel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqColorPicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        // set default value
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().colorPickerOptions || {};
        $(element).colorPicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).colorPicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);
        $(element).change();
    }
};


viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.coverTextColor = ko.observable('green');
    self.title = ko.observable('Hi there!');
};

ko.applyBindings( new viewModel() );
```

Any help appreciated.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/hmLbb9c0/2/

Comment: This post could be of help -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399892/jquery-color-picker-binding-handler-creates-multiple-divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `div` neither has a `change` event, nor can its content be read with jQuery `.val()` method.

The documentation [states](http://www.laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/) that you should use an input field, and having made that change alone you code works.

http://jsfiddle.net/48evdyvx/1/

Comment: IMO, the `viewModel` object could also stand to gain some sort of reference to `self` (i.e. `var self = this;`), as this would make debugging a little bit easier. http://jsfiddle.net/3kcuvd0n/