# Save wpColorPicker value with knockout custom bindings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, knockout.js

I use [wpColorPicker](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) and knockout. I am trying to have the value of the color picker updated in my observable and then stored in the database as JSON. I have other elements that update and save perfectly so it really is linked to my custom binding for the data picker.

I have looked at and tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399892/jquery-color-picker-binding-handler-creates-multiple-divs) but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is part of the script in my php file:

```
<div class="caption">
   <div class="label">
      <b><?php _e( 'Caption', 'lavilla' ); ?></b><br/>
      <textarea class="slide-caption" data-bind="value: slideCaption"></textarea>
      <br/>
      <p class="text-color"><span class="label"><?php _e( ' Text color', 'lavilla' ); ?></span><input data-bind="wpColorPicker: textColor"  /></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is in where I am with my JS:

```
function Slide(textColor) {
    var self = this;
    this.textColor = ko.observable(textColor);

    ko.bindingHandlers.wpColorPicker = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            // set default value
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).val(value);

            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().wpColorPickerOptions || {};
            $(element).wpColorPicker(options);


            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).val());
            });

            //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                $(element).wpColorPicker("destroy");
            });

        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).val(value);
            $(element).change();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: What does happen exactly, what is the error condition?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll do better writing your bindinghandler from scratch. There is a lot of not-helpful code in the one you're using. Your bindinghandler assignment should not be part of a constructor function (Slide), it should just be created once. Start by just wrapping the `value` binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wpcolorpicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    $(element).wpColorPicker();
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
  }
};
```

I don't have the wpColorPicker to play with, so I can't give you a complete answer. I suspect you'll need to use the `change` option of `wpColorPicker` to update your bound variable when a new color is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Roy J. I did start again from scratch and finally found how to write it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wpColorPicker = {
    init: function( element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var color = ko.unwrap( valueAccessor() );
        $( element ).val( color );
        var options= { 
            change: function (event, ui ) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                value( ui.color.toString() );
            },
        };
        $( element ).wpColorPicker( options );
    }
};
```

I do use the function change of wpColorPicker. The trick as well is that the color value is in decimal and I have to pass it in hexadecimal to knockout.